# Why when I write array.map, foreach, or a simple for, it runs async in Electron + Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, electron

I'm working in a project based in electron, node.js, javascript and react.

I'm trying to run some steps with each item inside an array, push the item into a second array and after that append the content to a string variable. My code looks something like the following:

```js
var originalStr = "A, B, C";
var firstArray = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
var secondArray = ['D', 'E', 'F'], 
var text = "";
console.log("Start of map"); //Should be printed before the execution of the map
firstArray.map((letter, i) => {
    console.log(letter); //Will print each letter
    originalStr = originalStr.replace(letter, secondArray[i]);
    line += originalStr + "\n";
);
console.log("End of map"); //Should be printed at the end of the execution
console.log(line); //Should print the array
```

But I get that the last message prints before the execution of the iteration, for example:

```
>Start of map
>End of map
>         <= empty array (line), should be "D, E, F"
>A
>B
>C
```

As you can see, the iteration is not being running in sequence, but first it executes the next line and then starts the iteration.
This code is being executed inside the renderer.

Comment: This is kinda unexpected. Do you run this code in main or in renderer?

Comment: Also your code is suspicious. First why are you using map for side-effects? Then if you need to append one array to another just use `secondArray.push(...firstArray)`.  For appending to a string use `str += firstArray.join('')`

Comment: Inside the renderer, I don't only append it, but change the string depending of another variable, This is just an example

Comment: I just modified the code to represent better what I want to do

Comment: Is this your actual code? I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: There is several issue with this code, specially map is not intended to be used like this. You also forgot to close one curly brace, so I guess you have formatting issue in your code. But again, don't write code like this, you will have a hard time reading it again in next 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var firstArray = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
console.log("Start of map"); 
const secondArray = firstArray.map((letter, i) => letter )
console.log("End of map"); 
console.log(secondArray);
```

Comment: I just modified the code to represent better what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

Try re-runing the below code. It is working for me.

```
var firstArray = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
var secondArray = [];
//var letter='sampleValue'
console.log("Start of map"); //Should be printed before the execution of the map
firstArray.map((letter,i)=>
{
    console.log(letter);
    secondArray.push(letter);
}
);
console.log("End of map"); //Should be printed at the end of the execution
console.log(secondArray); //Should print the array
```